# How do I grab the content from application form for multiple user and Display on a Tabular column in html

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, html-table

I am a beginner in Javascript, so kindly help. For a single user I have got the Display, but when I am submitting the second user contents or details the previous details are   overwritten. Actually what I need is every user contents has to bd Displayed column wise in Tabular column without replacing the  previous Details. Every time I type the second User contents or details in the Application form on the tabular column it will get replaced  and display the present user details.

```
  <body>
  <br name="myForm" action="/result.jsp" method="post" >
  <style>
  body{ height: 680px; margin: 20px; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #033371; border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px;}
p { display: table-row;}
label { margin-right: 40px; display: table-cell; width: 120px; }
input { margin-bottom: 5px; display: table-cell; padding:5px; border:1px solid #999;border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px;-web-kit-border-radius:4px;-khtml-border-radius:4px;
}
button{ background-color: #bde2f9; font-weight: 600;}
table, th { border: 1px solid black;}
td{font-weight:bold; width:160px; color:red; text-align: center;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>


<div>
<form name="firstform" id="firstform" method="post">
  <p id="p1">  </p>
  <label>Full Name:</label><input type="text"style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" name="fname" id="fname" size="35" value="" /><br/><br/>

  <div>
    <select name="DOBDay"style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="dobd">
      <option> - Day - </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="DOB" id="dobm"style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371">
      <option> - Month - </option>
      <option value="January">January</option>
      <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
      <option value="March">March</option>
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
      <option value="June">June</option>
      <option value="July">July</option>
      <option value="August">August</option>
      <option value="September">September</option>
      <option value="October">October</option>
      <option value="November">November</option>
      <option value="December">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="DOBYear"style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="doby">
      <option> - Year - </option>
      <option value="1993">1993</option>
      <option value="1992">1992</option>
      <option value="1991">1991</option>
      <option value="1990">1990</option>
      <option value="1989">1989</option>
      <option value="1988">1988</option>
      <option value="1987">1987</option>
      <option value="1986">1986</option>
      <option value="1985">1985</option>
      <option value="1984">1984</option>
      <option value="1983">1983</option>
      <option value="1982">1982</option>
      <option value="1981">1981</option>
      <option value="1980">1980</option>
      <option value="1979">1979</option>
      <option value="1978">1978</option>
      <option value="1977">1977</option>
      <option value="1976">1976</option>
      <option value="1975">1975</option>
      <option value="1974">1974</option>
      <option value="1973">1973</option>
      <option value="1972">1972</option>
      <option value="1971">1971</option>
      <option value="1970">1970</option>
      <option value="1969">1969</option>
      <option value="1968">1968</option>
      <option value="1967">1967</option>
      <option value="1966">1966</option>
      <option value="1965">1965</option>
      <option value="1964">1964</option>
      <option value="1963">1963</option>
      <option value="1962">1962</option>
      <option value="1961">1961</option>
      <option value="1960">1960</option>
      <option value="1959">1959</option>
      <option value="1958">1958</option>
      <option value="1957">1957</option>
      <option value="1956">1956</option>
      <option value="1955">1955</option>
      <option value="1954">1954</option>
      <option value="1953">1953</option>
      <option value="1952">1952</option>
      <option value="1951">1951</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="1949">1949</option>
      <option value="1948">1948</option>
      <option value="1947">1947</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <label>Username</label><input type="text" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" name="uname" id="uname" size="35" value="" /><br/><br/>


  Phone no:<input type="tel"name="number" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="usernr"/> <br/><br/>


  Address:<input type="text"name="usera" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="usera"/><br/><br/>


  Country:
  <select name="userCountry" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="userc">
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>other</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <label>Email</label><input type="email" name="email" style="font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';color: #033371" id="email" size="35" value="" />
  <br/><br/>

  <input type="button" value="SAVE" onclick="writeToPage()"style="font-family: fantasy;color: chartreuse;background-color: red">
  <br/><br/>



 <div id="pdada">
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>FULL NAME:</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>USER</th>
    <th>USER NO:</th>
    <th>USER ADDRESS:</th>
    <th>USER COUNTRY:</th>
    <th>EMAIL</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="fullname"></td>
    <td id="dobb"></td>
    <td id="username"></td>
    <td id="usernbr"></td>
    <td id="useradd"></td>
    <td id="usercty"></td>
    <td id="pemail"></td>
    <td id="adate"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>


<script>
var dt = new Date();

function writeToPage(){

  var fn = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var dob = document.getElementById("dobd").value+"/"+ document.getElementById("dobm").value+"/"+document.getElementById("doby").value;
  var un = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var unr= document.getElementById("usernr").value;
  var ua = document.getElementById("usera").value;
  var uc= document.getElementById("userc").value;
  var em = document.getElementById("email").value;
     for(i=0;i<i+1;i++) {
      i= document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML = fn;
     }
  document.getElementById("dobb").innerHTML = dob;
  document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = un;
  document.getElementById("usernbr").innerHTML = unr;
  document.getElementById("useradd").innerHTML = ua;
  document.getElementById("usercty").innerHTML = uc;
  document.getElementById("pemail").innerHTML = em;
  document.getElementById("adate").innerHTML = dt;


  document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("uname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("dobd").value = "";
  document.getElementById("dobm").value = "";
  document.getElementById("doby").value = "";
  document.getElementById("usernr").value = "";
  document.getElementById("usera").value = "";
  document.getElementById("userc").value = "";
  document.getElementById("email").value = "";

}
```

Comment: Where do you use Java?

Comment: in Intellij IDEA